# Formating `dtx` file wiht `latexindent`

Tags: dtx, latexindent

eI am currently writing a `dtx` file for a custom class. Does anybody have experiences with pretty-formatting both the source-code and the documentation inside the commends using something like `latexindent`? Or is there maybe a ready to got `localSettings.yaml` out there?

HEre is a simple `dtx` file to discuss about. Running `latexindent` on it will obviously only format the not-commented pars.

```latex
% \iffalse
%<*driver> ^^A ---------- documentation driver -----------------------------------------
\ProvidesFile{class.dtx}
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\begin{document}
\DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
% ^^A ---------- document body -----------------------------------------
% \title{A \LaTeX\ class}
% \maketitle
%
% \section{Introduction}
% This is just an example.
%
% \section{Class commands}
% You can use the following options:
%
% \begin{description}
% \item[foo] first command with long paragraph
% \item[bar] second command
% \end{description}
%
% \section{Implementation}
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<*class>
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{HsH-standalone}[2024-01-29 my cool class]
%    \end{macrocode}
%
% \subsection{Implement the commands}
%
% \begin{macro}{\foo}
% this is an example macro.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\def\foo{foo}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
%
% \begin{macro}{\bar}
% this is an example macro.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\def\bar{bar}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<*class>
%    \end{macrocode}
\endinput
```

Comment: Asked and answered at https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl/issues/513 I recommend this is closed